# how to dump or import a 4gb sized sql file using command prompt or sql buddy?

Tags: mysql

i am having a problem on importing a 4gb sized database. i need some sort of help please. i'm using wampserver. i already tried bigdump.php but it didn't work. I already configured my my.ini and php.ini but still it doesn't work. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer, although I didn't try it yet. 
Are you using a MyIsam or a INNOdb?
And are you using MySQL WORKBENCH for the import?
Doing my experiences, I was able to export an "INNOdb" 3,5 GB database into a self-contained SQL file in a question of 2 or 3 minutes. During the process it also shows where the restrictions might apply:

max_allowed_packet=1GB

Try START => SEARCH => max_allowed_packet

and change whatever you need to change (in the ini files, of course) to 5 GB, for example.

Perhaps it works!  ; )